# html binded variable to C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, data-binding, javascript-databinding

I have a variable called "selectedAssignment" that is binded in the html, and I want to access it from C#.

right now what I am doing is:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="assignmentName" Value="{{selectedAssignment.name}}"/>
```

And in C#:

```
String assignment = assignmentName.Value;
```

This works fine the first time, but then when the variable changes, the value stays the same (not only in the backend, but also in the html).
Also, {{selectedAssignment.name}} does update in places where it's not a value attribute, like headers.

How can I make it update in the hiddenfield?

Comment: C# runs on server side and so you wont get real time updates on valies.  They dont update unless some sort of action is taken.  A button press, an onchange event is triggered from UI side, or something else

Comment: How are you setting the value? Are you changing `assignment` or `assignmentName.Value`?

Comment: The assignment is changed when another assignment is chosen. I can see that the variable does change correctly in places where the {{selectedAssignment.name}} is in the inner text (like headers) but not in that specific line